# The south India datacenter seems to be failing. The /me endpoint is failing

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The south India datacenter seems to be failing. The /me endpoint is failing

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
Is returning:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
request-id: dd27a36f-8345-4150-964a-96c3bfc96670
client-request-id: dd27a36f-8345-4150-964a-96c3bfc96670
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South India","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_0","ADSiteName":"MAA"}}
Duration: 4.3537
Date: Fri, 03 Feb 2017 08:06:51 GMT
Content-Length: 252
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "dd27a36f-8345-4150-964a-96c3bfc96670",
      "date": "2017-02-03T08:06:52"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a service issue that caused such failures and it has been mitigated now. Please let us know if you continue to see the error.